# XCUITest get URL value

Tags: ios, xcode8, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation

I am using XCUITest with XCode version 8.3.3.  The application has a login button which launches a browser window.  Was wondering if someone could tell me how I can access the value of the URL that gets opened.  I want to verify we launch the correct URL when selecting the Login button.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let loginButton = app.buttons["Login"]
loginButton.tap()
```

At this point the browser window is open:[image]

**How can I get the value of xyz.com?**

Using the Accessibility Inspector, I can see:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a small project that loading google.com in an SFSafariViewController on launch. When I run UI tests against this app and prints the debug description of the window, I get the following:

```
(lldb) po XCUIApplication().windows.descendants(matching: .any)
    t =    29.26s     Use cached accessibility hierarchy for com.tito.Safari
    t =    29.27s     Find: Descendants matching type Window
    t =    29.27s     Find: Descendants matching type Any
Find: Target Application 0x6000000afa20
  Output: {
    Application 0x6000001684c0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: 'Safari'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Window
    Output: {
      Window 0x600000169a80: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window 0x60000016a8c0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window 0x60000016fb40: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window 0x60000016c780: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window 0x600000169e40: {{-0.0, -0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
    }
    ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Any
      Output: {
        Button 0x608000169900: traits: 8589934593, {{9.5, 22.0}, {43.0, 34.0}}, label: 'Done'
        Other 0x608000165b80: traits: 8589935104, {{68.5, 24.5}, {295.0, 29.0}}, identifier: 'URL', label: 'Address', value: 10%
        Button 0x608000169840: traits: 8589934593, {{336.5, 24.5}, {29.0, 29.0}}, identifier: 'StopButton', label: 'stop'
        Button 0x600000168100: traits: 146028888065, {{66.5, 24.5}, {299.0, 29.0}}, identifier: 'URL', label: 'Address', value: ‎google.com
        Other 0x6080001696c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
        WebView 0x608000167ec0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x608000167e00: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x608000169b40: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x608000167a40: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 622.5}, {375.0, 0.5}}
        Button 0x6080001675c0: traits: 8589934849, {{0.5, 625.0}, {42.0, 40.0}}, label: 'Back'
        Button 0x600000167bc0: traits: 8589934849, {{104.0, 625.0}, {42.0, 40.0}}, label: 'Forward'
        Button 0x600000167c80: traits: 8589934593, {{207.5, 624.0}, {51.0, 40.0}}, label: 'Share'
        Button 0x60000016fa80: traits: 8589934593, {{320.5, 625.5}, {55.0, 40.0}}, label: 'Open in Safari'
        Toolbar 0x608000167b00: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 623.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
        Other 0x608000165ac0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x608000169780: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x608000169480: 
        Other 0x608000169180: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x60000016cc00: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {24.0, 603.0}}
        Other 0x6080001690c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x600000168400: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x600000169180: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x600000169f00: 
        Other 0x60000016a680: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x600000167b00: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
        Other 0x60000016fd80: traits: 8388608, {{6.0, 0.0}, {39.0, 20.0}}
        Other 0x60000016e340: traits: 8388608, {{50.0, 0.0}, {13.0, 20.0}}, label: '3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars', value: SSID
        Other 0x60000016fe40: traits: 8389120, {{161.0, 0.0}, {57.0, 20.0}}, label: '10:33 AM'
        Other 0x60000016e880: traits: 8388608, {{337.0, 0.0}, {33.0, 20.0}}, label: '-100% battery power'
        Other 0x60000016dc80: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
        StatusBar 0x600000169240: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
        Other 0x60000016a440: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x600000170140: 
        Other 0x60000016da40: traits: 8589934592, {{-0.0, -0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
        Other 0x60000016c600: 
        Other 0x60000016af80: traits: 8589934592, {{-0.0, -0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      }
```

You can see that the element that contain the value `google.com` is seen as a Button that the Accessibility framework.

```
Button 0x600000168100: traits: 146028888065, {{66.5, 24.5}, {299.0, 29.0}}, identifier: 'URL', label: 'Address', value:
```

It seems wrong but it is how it is and there's nothing you can do about that. The way to access this element's value would be the following

```
XCUIApplication().buttons['URL'].value!
```

The only problem is that it's returns the following

```
‎gen.xyz, secure and validated connection
```

So the last thing to do is to parse this and you'll get the address

```
let value = XCUIApplication().buttons["URL"].value as! String
let address = value.components(separatedBy: ",").first!
```

This is definitely hacky though and might change in the future if Apple decides to apply their own advices to their own products when it comes to Accessibility.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!! Very helpful.

Comment: When the value comes back, it has \u(e2) at the beginning, do you know why?

Comment: Hmm no, what URL are you trying to load?

Comment: Check out this post where I was able to add screenshots and more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955383/swift-xcui-string-assertion-failing

Comment: Did you try with another URL like to see if the problem came from there?

Answer (score 2):

for Xcode 13 to run on iOS 15 I have used this code

```
let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")
safari.textFields["Address"].tap()
let val = safari.textFields["Address"].value as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the other responses to not get the full URL. Both methods will only get you the domain name.

By first tapping the URL bar I can then get the value of the resulting text field.

```
let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")
safari.buttons["URL"].tap()
let url = safari.textFields["URL"].value as! String
```

Then assert on that.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get `URL` from `Safari` in iOS 13.5

```
override public func setUpWithError() throws {
        app = XCUIApplication()
        safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")

        app.launch()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

func test_URL() throws {
        safari.launch()
        safari.buttons.matching(identifier: "URL").element(at: 0).value
    }
```