# Swift XCUI string assertion failing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation

I am using xcode 8.3.3 and writing a XCUI test.

I have the following:
`let address = XCUIApplication().buttons["URL"].value as! String`

Looking in the debugger, I can see the value is:

[image]

If I set
`expectedURL = "\u{e2}auth.int....net"` then it returns:[image]

If I set
`expectedURL = "auth.int....net"` then it returns:[image]

**How can I make the test assertion find the two strings to be equal?**

Tried the following, but it doesn't replace the "\u{e2}":

```
let address = value.components(separatedBy: ",").first!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{e2}", with: "")
```

And also (but it doesn't replace the "\u{e2}"):

`let range = Range<String.Index>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: address.startIndex, upper: address.endIndex))`

```
let strippedAddress = address.replacingOccurrences(of:"\\u{e2}", with: "", options: .literal, range: range)
```

For the assertion, I am using `XCTAssertEqual(address, expectedURL)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix it by separating by alphanumeric characters and then joining by an empty string, as shown below.

```
let myString = address.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined(separator: "")
```

`myString`is then equal to authintxxxxxxxxxnet (no "." characters), so you should just be able to change your expected URL to match.

Hope that helps!